# Using Switch Statement for Filtering Search Categories

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the search feature in my Angular 2 app, I have a set of filters (using material2's md-slide-toggle buttons) that a user can click on to filter by category. It looks like this:

```
<div><md-slide-toggle value="group1" name="category" [(ngModel)]="group1" (click)="group1Select()"> Group 1</md-slide-toggle></div>
<div><md-slide-toggle value="group2" name="category" [(ngModel)]="group2" (click)="group2Select()"> Group 2</md-slide-toggle></div>
<div><md-slide-toggle value="group3" name="category" [(ngModel)]="grpup3" (click)="group3Select()"> Group 3</md-slide-toggle></div>
<div><md-slide-toggle value="group4" name="category" [(ngModel)]="group4" (click)="group4Select()"> Group 4</md-slide-toggle></div>
<div><button md-raised-button name="category" (click)="refresh()">RESET</button></div>
```

Then, in my component, I am setting the category so that if a user, for instance, clicks on the first option, it'd trigger this function:

```
public group1Select() {
    this.category = 'group1';
}
```

This will set the category and a new list of 10 results coming from JUST that category are generated. This is working perfectly.

We have our api set up to use a delimited list, so it can receive either a single value, or a series of values separated by a comma. So with my reset button, for instance, I have a "search.refesh" function that triggers a new list of 10 results to be generated, and as you'll see below I'm setting the "category" to include ALL categories, by simply listing them all):

```
public refresh(): void {
    this.search.refresh();
    this.category = 'group1,group2,group3,group4';
```

What I'd like to do now is set up some conditional logic so that if a user selects, say, the buttons for both "group1" and "group2", that the results would include results for just those two categories. In other words, the logic would be "this.category = 'group1, group2'", because the user first selected the button for group 1, and then, without deselecting that button, ALSO clicked on button 2. So the 10 generated results should include results from just those two categories.

Here's my question: How can I set up the logic to handle various scenarios of button selections? Would I use switch statements? Or just if/else statements? Or is another approach better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "*creating*" those `components` (and also `methods`) manually, I'd create an `array` of `objects` and bind it using *ngFor*, so it'll be simpler to get which `groups` are checked.

**Component:**

```
this.categories = [
  { name: 'Group 1', value: 'group1', checked: false },
  { name: 'Group 2', value: 'group2', checked: false },
  { name: 'Group 3', value: 'group3', checked: false },
  { name: 'Group 4', value: 'group4', checked: false }
];

onChecked(): void {
  const checkedGroups: string = this.categories.filter(x => !!x.checked)
                                               .map(x => x.value)
                                               .join(','));
  // do what you want with the checked groups
  console.log(checkedGroups);
}
...
```

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
  <md-slide-toggle [name]="category.name" (change)="onChecked()" [(ngModel)]="category.checked">{{category.name}}</md-slide-toggle>
</div>
<div><button md-raised-button name="category" (click)="refresh()">RESET</button></div>
```

**PS:** Note that I'm using `(change)`, not `(click)` *$event*.

**Plunker**: <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zgBXB9E3H1hH9M2vH5YN?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: This looks like a very effective and elegant approach. I will give it a try. Thanks!